# oozie-Unable to name any Action or Control nodes of oozie with numbers

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a oozie workflow which has many control and action nodes. To make it a bit easy to track the actions in Hue browser, I tried to number the control and action nodes by prefixing 1,2,3 and so on, to the name of the nodes. 
Here is the workflow snippet

```
<workflow-app name="reporting_W_error_audit_report" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="1_JobInitiated_SendMail" />
    <action name='1_JobInitiated_SendMail'>
        <email xmlns='uri:oozie:email-action:0.1'>
            <to>${failureEmailToAddress}</to>
            <subject>The workflow has been kicked off at ${timestamp()}</subject>
            <body>The workflow "${wf:name()}" with workflow id "${wf:id()}" has been started at ${timestamp()} and is currently running. You will get further notification upon its Success or Failure.</body>
        </email>
        <ok to='2_rename_trigger_flag_file_processing'/>
        <error to='2_rename_trigger_flag_file_processing' />
    </action>
    <action name="02_rename_trigger_flag_file_processing">
        <fs>
...
...
```

While validating the workflow I got the below error.

```
Error: E0701: XML schema error, /dn01/home/testarea/wf.xml, org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 40; cvc-pattern-valid: Value '1_JobInitiated_SendMail' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '([a-zA-Z_]([\-_a-zA-Z0-9])*){1,39}' for type 'IDENTIFIER'.
```

How can I get rid of this error as I want to number the node names?

Comment: The error has all the info you need. Your name have all the info that you need - just make your name match the pattern

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I should post the answer as I managed to get this working. What I discovered is that the name of the nodes cannot be started with numbers however it can accommodate numbers anywhere else. I just tried to name one of the nodes with suffixing numbers and it worked. Working code snippet below..

```
<workflow-app name="reporting_W_error_audit_report" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="JobInitiated_SendMail_01" />
    <action name='JobInitiated_SendMail_01'>
        <email xmlns='uri:oozie:email-action:0.1'>
            <to>${failureEmailToAddress}</to>
            <subject>The workflow has been kicked off at ${timestamp()}</subject>
            <body>The workflow "${wf:name()}" with workflow id "${wf:id()}" has been started at ${timestamp()} and is currently running. You will get further notification upon its Success or Failure.</body>
        </email>
        <ok to='rename_trigger_flag_file_processing_02'/>
        <error to='rename_trigger_flag_file_processing_02' />
    </action>
    <action name="rename_trigger_flag_file_processing_02">
...
...
```